Despite method being POST, its a GET when implemented
I'm trying to use the ChatGPT API and I'm using POST as the method to send it to the API, however, on the page when I hit the submit button, it doesn't go through. When, in the browser's dev console, I hit "open in new tab", It says "cannot GET /ask".
This is the server.js code:
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const OpenAI = require("openai");
const cors = require ('cors')
const path = require('path')

// Initialization
const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: "sk-proj-BLAHBLAHBLAHAPIKEY",
});

const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.post('/ask', async (req, res) => {
  const { question } = req.body;
  console.log('Received question:', question);  // Log the received question

  try {
    console.log('Sending request to OpenAI...');
    const response = await client.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [{ role: "user", content: question }],
    });

    console.log('OpenAI response:', response.data);  // Log the full response object
    res.json({ answer: response.data.choices[0].message.content });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error communicating with OpenAI:', error);  // Log the error
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to generate response from OpenAI API' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

This is the index.html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Book Q&A</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Ask about the Books</h1>
  <input type="text" id="question" placeholder="Ask a question">
  <button onclick="askQuestion()">Ask</button>
  <p id="answer"></p>

  <script>
    async function askQuestion() {
      const question = document.getElementById('question').value;
      console.log('Sending question:', question);  // Log the question being sent

      const response = await fetch('/ask', {  // Use relative path
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ question }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch response:', response.statusText);  // Log if the request failed
        document.getElementById('answer').innerText = 'Error: ' + response.statusText;
        return;
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Received response:', data.answer);  // Log the received response
      document.getElementById('answer').innerText = data.answer;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

A couple of things:

Yes, I know the API key can be put in the ".env." I just want it to work first, and then I'll move it there in the next iteration.
I've asked ChatGPT for help on this, but the only trained API documentation is v3x, while the current API is v4x.

When I run server.js, it runs and gives me the message "Server is running on http://localhost:3001," so it is running. The index page loads; it just doesn't go through when I hit the ask/submit button.
I'm sure it's something stupid, but what am I missing?
I've reinstalled the API and reinstalled the modules listed in the script. Reinstalled NGINX.
What I was expecting is that when I type a question and hit "Ask" i get a response that's hopefully close to the answer I was expecting.

What are you clicking on when you select Open in a New Window?

The browser isn't calling the OpenAI API. When you click on a URL in DevTools and tell it to open the URL, it acts like you pasted the URL into the URL bar of the window, so it uses a GET request.

It doesn't resubmit the same Fetch request, so the original POST method is ignored.

Is the client index.html also running on http://localhost:3001? If not, you may change the fetch url to fetch("http://localhost:3001/ask").

Another way to test if your POST request on your http://localhost:3001 is working, is to use an app like Postman.

@Kokodoko, I'm running it from a Digital Ocean droplet to work on different computers. I tried using http://localhost:3001/ask, and now I get (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

You need to run server.js under node.js on your computer for localhost:3001 to work

First make sure your node.js is even running, you can even do that with an online tool such as "https://hoppscotch.io". If you are sure the node server/ask page returns results, then you can look at why your fetch isn't working.
